# using self.request.get to query the datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i am trying to do something like

```
     try:
       q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM people WHERE location = :loc", loc = location).fetch(1)
       self.render('experimentform.html', q = q)
    except:
        render('experimentform.html')
        location = self.request.get('location')
```

to allow users to query the datastore using a drop down menu.

it works up to rendering experimentform, but after location has been submitted i get a 405 error, method post is not allowed.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you add the code of the handler that you execute the above code snippet?

Comment: Why would you think that the 405 error has anything to do with querying the datastore? Quite obviously you're not even getting that far.

Comment: im not saying its to to with querying the datastore. what i am saying is after i have submitted the initial form i get a 405 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are submitting your form as a POST but you don't (by the sound of it) have a POST hander configured.

so where you have

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        do something with a get request
```

you need this as well:

```
 class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            *do something with a post request*
```

Or you could reconfigure your form to use GET instead of POST and leave your current code alone:

```
<form name="input" action="website_action" method="get">
```

Comment: i knew i was doing something stupid, thanks. one of those things ill hopefully remember in the future.